# Adding a private key to X509Certificate2 - C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509, private-key, x509certificate2

I'm new to 2WaySSL.

What I'm trying to do:

```
1. Retrieve a Client certificate which is stored in a certificate store,
I'm managing to do that by such code:



 certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serialNumber, false);
```

When attaching the certificate to the request, the authentication by the server fails,
since I the certificate object does not contain the private key.

I'm trying to find a way of associating the private key to the certificate (in c#),
Once I'll retrieve the key from where it's stored.

something like:

```
   certificate.PrivateKey = key;
```

But I found no easy way of either initiating the key object, or assigning it to the certificate without getting some exception, even when the key is null, I'm getting an access denied exception.

Any help , especially followed by a code sample, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

AFter .NET 4.7.2, If you have the certificate with only public key and an RSA private key handy you can perform the below code

```
certificate= certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(key);
```

you have to import System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 easy options

- import certificate with private key (usually a pfx file) to certificate store. Then `store.Certificates.Find` will retrieve the certificate with private key.
- Load pfx file into `X509Certificate2` istance with one of its constructors `new X509Certificate2(pfx_filename, password_to_pfx)`

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Regarding the PFX file,
If it contains the password,
Doesn't it mean that anyone that gets access to the file, gets the password as well?

Shouldn't the password be stored elsewhere, and not within the certificate file?

Comment: The private key in pfx file is secured with this password. The password itself is not part of the file. But if using a pfx file there is a possibility to copy the file elsewhere (if someone has access to the filesystem) and try to guess the password by brute force. I prefer using certificate store. When security is main priority I use HSM to store private key (or a smartcard) but certificate is still in certificate store.

Comment: I must be missing something.
I opened the certificate snap in (using mmc), accessed the relevant certificate store, and viewed the certificate.
After finding its serial number, under the details tab, I used the following code:
certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serialNumber, false);

Now I got access to the certificate and its private key, using:
certificates[0].PrivateKey.ToXmlString(false)
Thoughts?

Comment: What has changed? Do you use different store now? Or serial number is different? Or do you run the test under different credentials (user)?

Comment: I'll try to explain further:
1. I got a client certificate, provided to me. I should be able to generate one myself (I have access to both server and the client machines and the CA).
2. The client certificate provided is signed with a private key (hope I got the terminology right), I spot this by the key icon in the certificate store, and double clicking the certificate, I see: “you have a private key that corresponds to this certificate”
3. I want to generate a client certificate, without the private key, and in my code, load the key from somewhere, and associate it with the certificate.